# Android Alarm Manager doesn't work

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

So I have a `BroadcastReceiver` which looks like this:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public UpdateReceiver() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 10);
        System.out.println("Broadcast received");       

        PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,new Intent("REFRESH_THAT"), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);       
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, System.currentTimeMillis(), cal.getTimeInMillis(), operation);
    }
}
```

This is how I call the `BroadcastReceiver`

```
 Intent in = new Intent ("REFRESH_BROADCAST");       
 sendBroadcast(in);
```

And this is my intent-filter in Android `Manifest` file

```
<service android:name = ".services.RefreshService">     
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="REFRESH_THAT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<receiver android:name=".services.UpdateReceiver">        
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="REFRESH_BROADCAST"/>        
    </intent-filter>    
</receiver>
```

`BroadcastReceiver` received a brodcast without any problem, but `AlarmManager` seems to do nothing. If I call `operation.send()` it works without a problem, so I presume there is something wrong with `AlarmManager`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright so finally I found a solution a it was my fault.

I have set `int type` to `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` and  `long triggerAtMillis` to `System.currentTimeMillis()` property of `alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(.....)` which is wrong, it only can be paired with `AlarmManager.RTC / RTC_WAKEUP`.

So the functional code is this:

```
PendingIntent operation = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0,new Intent("REFRESH_THAT"), 0);       
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 30000, operation);
```

I should really read API documentation more carefully. If you hover `AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME` , it will told you what kind of time trigger you have to use. Hope this my stupid mistake will help someone in future.

Comment: Have you got your BroadcastReceiver set up? I could provide a code, if you have trouble with that. But firstly make sure, you got it registered in the Android Manifest. LIke in my original question.

Comment: I copy pasted your example and it worked fine. Thanks. But there things I seem not to understand. Please explain to me this line:
`alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() , 30000, operation);
`
Does it mean in your case operations will happen after 30 seconds or?

I mean does it mean your timer interval is 30s

Comment: It work pretty much the same way, like Cron on Linux, if something is about to fire it up the radio 5 seconds ahead, it waits that 5 seconds, it's for power saving..In my first post I tried to get things working, but today, it's about 5 minutes or more, it runs a synchronization class for server.and the client. But I am sure that you wouldn't want to look at adb monitor for so long. With the AlarmManager, just like it is in OP (which is corrected in this post), it runs a Android Service on the background every 30 seconds. Is that clear, what am I saying?

Answer (score 0):

As per the [`setInexactRepeating`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setInexactRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) doc, The third parameter is:

> > intervalMillis:   interval in milliseconds between subsequent repeats of the alarm

Then you should put `10000` ms (which is 10 sec) instead of `cal.getTimeInMillis()`

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME, cal.currentTimeMillis(), 10000, operation);
```

Which means that, youer alarm will go off after 10 sec of the intent firing, then will repeat each 10 sec. And of course, since you are using this method, This is inexact timing.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I am going to try that.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either. Worst thing is, that I don't get any errors. So it seems like it simply doesn't work. It really drives me insane...

Comment: How do you know that `RefreshService` didn't start? did you add some sort of logging there? And are you using inexact timing for a reason? Did you consider using [setRepeating()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating%28int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29) instead?

Comment: Yeah, I have there a System.out.println("Service Called"). And I have reason for inexact repeating, because this should call a intentService, which fetch data to database. So I don't to drain users battery more than I need to. But I am gonna try setRepeating() and see what happens : )